# Avoid Duplicate Meta Description and Keywords in Next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, meta-tags

I'm developing my website with **Next.js** To upgrade my website's SEO performance, I'm trying to avoid duplicated meta tags.

**My Question**

In Next official docs, they say that I can avoid overlapped meta tag by insert key property in meta tag. But this does not work.

```
<meta name="description" content="~~" key="titleDescription"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="~~" key="titleKeywords"/>
```

These are default rootDocument meta tags and,

```
<meta name="description" content={item.product_description} key="titleDescription"></meta>
<meta name="keywords" content={item.brand_name} key="titleKeywords"></meta>
```

These are dynamically generated meta tags in item pages.

In deployed browser, there are still two description and keywords meta tags in website. I want to avoid duplicated meta tag. *Thank you for your help!*

Comment: Where are you setting the default meta tags?

Comment: @juliomalves Default meta tags are in <head> at _document.js. and others are dynamically created in pages directory. Thank you!

Comment: @Han did you manage to solve the issue? For me, it duplicates some of the tags and some work as expected. At the same time, the declarations are the same in all places.

Answer (score 33):

There are a few things to watch for when using Next.js `Head` components.

- The `_document` `Head` component is `next/document`
- Tags in `_document` will not be replaced (can be duplicated) even with a `key` identifier
- The `_app` `Head` component is `next/head`
- Tags in `_app` can be in child components
- Tags in `_app` can be overridden with the `key` identifier
- Tags in pages **cannot** be in child components
- Tags in pages can override tags with the same `key` identifier.

---

## Examples

---

### _document.{js|jsx|ts|tsx}

Scripts, styles, and other tags you need access to immediately - Next will likely not be fully mounted at this point.  You cannot replace tags in the `document/head` component with the `key` attribute.

```
import Document, {Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render = () => (
    <Html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
      <Head>
        <script src="/some-script.js" defer={false} />
        <style>.inline-styles{}</style>
        {/* META & TITLE TAGS PLACED HERE CANNOT BE OVERRODE */}
      </Head>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

OR self-closing `Head` tag

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render = () => (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

*Note: import is from next/**document***

---

### _app.{js|jsx|ts|tsx}

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title key="title">App Tittle</title>
    </Head>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
);
```

OR load from a custom component

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const MyHeadTags = () => (
 <Head>
  <title key="title">App Tittle</title>
  <meta key="description" name="description">Description</meta>
 </Head>
);

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <>
    <MyHeadTags />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
);
```

*Note: import is from next/**head***

---

### some_page.{js|jsx|ts|tsx}

```
const SomePage = () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title key="title">Some Page Tittle</title>
      <meta key="description" name="description">Some Page Description</meta>
    </Head>
    <div>My Page</div>
  </>
);
```

### NOT ALLOWED

The head component must be on the page and cannot be a child component. If it's a child component, it sometimes will not override other tags with the same key property.

### some_page.{js|jsx|ts|tsx}

```
const MyHeadTags = () => (
 <Head>
  <title key="title">Some Page</title>
  <meta key="description" name="description">Some Page Description</meta>
 </Head>
);

const ChildComponent = () => (
 <>
  <MyHeadTags />
  Info.
 </>
);

const SomePage= () => (
  <>
    <ChildComponent />
    <div>Will not work</div>
  </>
);
```

***Update***: The last example seems to work in some cases with Next 11+, but I have run into a few instances where it duplicates tags. I avoid the last method.

Comment: Why isn't [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) a copy of this answer?! :-)

Comment: The Next answer works inconsistently in the last few sites I've built when child components set the tags. I've switched to next-seo without any issues.

Comment: That's good to know. I was simply scratching my head, because I had followed the official documentation to the word and it didn't work as expected. Your answer cleared up those questions for me. In my opinion it's indicative of the oversimplified documentation (or overcomplicated implementation) of this feature.

Comment: This distinction between `next/document` and `next/head` is mentioned on [advanced-features/custom-document#caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats) _(it is not mentioned under [next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head))_

Comment: "The head component must be on the page and cannot be a child component." SAVED MY DAY!!! Thank you @SeanW

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Here's what Next.js docs say regarding the `<Head />` element within the `_document.js` file:

> The  component used here is not the same one from next/head.
> The  component used here should only be used for any 
> code that is common for all pages. For all other cases, such as
> `<title>` tags, we recommend using next/head in your pages or
> components.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Therefore, Next.js recommends that all the dynamic `<meta />` tags should only be defined on an individual page level.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWEAR** (it seemed to work at first, but as it turns out, only at random).

This issue seems to appear when you mix up two ways of closing empty HTML tags in JSX. Notice that your `meta` tags in the `_document.js` file are self-closing: `<meta />` and the dynamic ones are not: `<meta></meta>`.

Ensure you are consistent with it (i.e. according to best practices you should convert all empty tags to the self-closing variant) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. This might be the case for OP. In my case, all are self closing. Any ideas? The only difference is I have tsx and the page is SSR rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can take a look at this package that helps managing meta tags https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo in Next.js project. It helped me :D

For your question, yea try putting the Head in the _app instead of _document. _document is like non mutated one.. it will be always in the website. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use Next 12.
Thanks to Sean's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68539324/10707183), I was able to progress.

I personally update the tags for SEO purpose according to the consulted page with a component Seo that I crafted.
But to prevent importing it in every pages, I wanted to import it once. It happened that importing this Seo component in pages/_app.js was eventually just duplicating the tags and especially breaking my social media links.

So here is my code.

First the Seo component:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import {SEO} from '@/Constants/seo'

const titlePrepend = 'WeekandGO | '
const Seo = ({ seo }) => {
  const currentUrl = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.href

  const defaultSeo = {...SEO['index']}

  let seoWithDefaults = {...defaultSeo}

  if (seo) {
    seoWithDefaults = {
      ...seoWithDefaults,
      ...seo,
    }
  }

  const fullSeo = {
    ...seoWithDefaults,
    metaTitle: seoWithDefaults?.metaTitle ? `${titlePrepend}${seoWithDefaults.metaTitle}` : `${titlePrepend}${defaultSeo.metaTitle}`,
    shareImage: seoWithDefaults?.shareImage || defaultSeo.shareImage,
    metaDescription: seoWithDefaults?.metaDescription || defaultSeo.metaDescription,
  }

  return <Head>
    <title>{fullSeo.metaTitle}</title>

    <meta name="Author" lang="fr" content="Leb Communication"/>
    <meta name="Identifier-URL" content="www.weekandgo.com"/>
    <meta name="Reply-to" content=""/>
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="7"/>
    <meta name="Publisher" content="WeekandGO"/>
    <meta name="Copyright" content="WeekandGO"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.weekandgo.com/" />
    <meta name="keywords" content={fullSeo.metaKeywords} />
    <meta name="description" content={fullSeo.metaDescription} />
    <meta name="image" content={fullSeo.shareImage} />

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="WeekandGO" />
    <meta property="og:url" content={currentUrl || 'https://www.weekandgo.com/'} />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content={fullSeo.shareImage} />
    <meta property="og:title" content={fullSeo.metaTitle} />
    <meta property="og:description" content={fullSeo.metaDescription} />

    <meta name="twitter:title" content={fullSeo.metaTitle} />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content={fullSeo.metaDescription} />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content={fullSeo.shareImage} />
  </Head>
}

export default Seo
```

I use it in pages/_document.js:

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="fr">
        <Head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/uah4cdm.css" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key>" type="text/javascript"/>
        </Head>
        <Seo/>
        <body className={ !isMobile && 'u-hover-on'}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

Then I import this component in pages/_document.js as so:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect'
import Seo from '@/Shared/Seo'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="fr">
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/uah4cdm.css" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDiB40c-5x-GAEBw3mIJXPTvamFHUV536I" type="text/javascript"/>
        </Head>
        <Seo/>
        <body className={ !isMobile && 'u-hover-on'}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Then, let me spare you some lines to just look at the return of my functional component App in pages/_app.js. There is no import of Seo component, only a ** Head coming from 'next/head' ** is used :

```
...
  return (<SessionProvider session={session}>
    <TokensRefresher/>
    <Head>
      <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </Head>
    <GlobalContextProvider appProps={{ global, categoryAnnexes, categoriesInfos }}>
      <GlobalLayout error={error}>
        <Component {...rest} />
      </GlobalLayout>
    </GlobalContextProvider>
  </SessionProvider>)
}
...
```

And finally, here is a page I receive data from server side props and that I want to use to change the meta tags related to seo. Here again I don't show the part of the code that are useless for the matter :

```
...
const Annonce = ({ ad, ...pageProps }) => {
  return <>
    <Seo seo={{metaTitle: ad?.slug, metaDescription: ad?.dealerWord, shareImage: ad?.firstImage?.fileUrl}} />
    <AnnonceLayout ad={ad} {...pageProps} />
  </>
}
...
```

The result I have in the source code is there is no duplicated meta tags and I can share my links on social medias with no image, description or page tilte overlaps

Comment: I still have to figure out why my sharing links are not containing the meta I expect but I've no duplicate in metas and the metas I wanted to have in source code are the ones I expected