# NextJS translate <Head> in _document

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

Is there a chance I can utilize `next-i18next` package for adding the translation support for a `<Head>` component in a `_document` file? Since the translation string injection happens in an `_app` file, can this somehow be adjusted to support translations for meta tags?

Exaple:

```js
<meta name="description" content={ t('header:description') } />
```

Comment: You could just move your meta tags to `_app` directly and translate them there. This also allows you to properly dedupe meta tags if needed - see [Avoid Duplicate Meta Description and Keywords in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204973/avoid-duplicate-meta-description-and-keywords-in-next-js).